# HTML link displaying in browser

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck in the first few steps of developing a very basic static website. I began by typing out my header and then I created a main.css file in a css directory and I set the body background color as a test to verify that the link is working. When I preview index.html in the browser, I'm not getting a color for the body but I'm also getting the text of my link showing up above the header. I believe I'm following the right protocol and can not figure out why this is. Any ideas? T.I.A.

File structure:
css
 main.css
 normalize.css

index.html

Browser preview:

rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

Quiet Woods

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title> Quiet Woods </title>
           <link> rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link> rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> 
      </head>
      <body>
      <header>
           <h1> Quiet Woods </h1>
      </header>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: `<link> rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">` should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">`. You have that extra `>` in both `link` tags

Comment: Ah! I figured it was some kind of simple typo. Works now. A million thanks!

Comment: NP. I can submit this as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You must remove the `>` character:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
```